# Cheat sheet of routes on graphs (Graph theory)

Tags: graph-theory

I created this cheat sheet in order for me to understand and memorize all these different types of routes better. I am somewhat sure that it is fully correct, although I would appreciate it if a blessed soul would double-check it.

One last thing that I am not fully certain about: are the two "not a cycle" (at the end of the cheat sheet) really not cycles?

[image: gra]

**Edit**

The final version of the cheat sheet:

[image]

Comment: If you want to feel slightly better about the number of definitions, you can forget entirely about trails and circuits on the first pass. I generally skip these two definitions when teaching intro graph theory; they are relevant almost exclusively in the context of Eulerian trails and Eulerian circuits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all sounds correct and indeed the non-examples of cycles pictured are in fact *not* cycles.  The intuitive comparison of cycles being "like circles" is the correct one.  More specifically $\color{blue}{A}EC\color{red}{A}DB\color{blue}{A}$ fails because of the red $A$ in the middle is the same vertex as what appears elsewhere.  There must be only one vertex that appears more than once, that vertex may only appear exactly twice, and the positions of said vertex can only be at the start and end, not anywhere else.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I got confused by it though. Do you mean the "circuit" AEADBA should be a counterexample as opposed to an example? Also, is the "not a cycle" AEDACBA really not a cycle?

Comment: "counterexample" and "nonexample" are similar words.  In my mind, the word nonexample is more appropriate here.  Counterexamples are more specifically things which show a generic proposition to be false.  Here we are merely showing an example of something which does not have a particular property, but we aren't necessarily proving a proposition false (*unless you want to take as a proposition "every thing is a cycle..." to which, yes it would then be a counterexample to that statement*).  Yes, the other circuit mentioned is also not a cycle for the exact same reason.

Comment: got it, thank you!